# How to create a curved gauge having linear-gradient as background?

Tags: html, css, border, linear-gradients

I want to make a 0-100% responsive gauge with pure css, with a color gradient from green to red. I found some examples but couldn't get a gradient working right in any of them. After some testing I managed to get it kinda working. It's basically a background div with a linear gradient background, and a white foreground div with half transparent borders, using border-radius to make them round. When I rotate the foreground div it reveals or obscure parts of the gradient background div.

But I have this visual glitch that I don't know how to fix:

[image: CSS gauge with gradient]

The white borders of the foreground div are not completely obscuring the gradient div.

This is my test code (it may contain unnecessary css rules from all the previous tests I did):

https://jsfiddle.net/fLtzrg3w/

HTML:

```
  <div class="c">
    <div class="go">
      <div class="g"></div>
      <div class="gbg"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
.c{
  position: relative;
  float:left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 25% 5px 0 5px;
  height: 1rem;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.go{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top:100%;
  margin-top: -50%;
}

.g{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
  border-right-color: #fff;
  transform: rotate(20deg);
  background: white;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  z-index: 2;
}

.gbg{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green 0%, yellow 50%, red 100%);
  z-index: 1;
}
```

How can I make the white div completely cover the background gradient div?

Comment: This might help: https://codepen.io/xgh/pen/ExaXgbb

Comment: @Mech I think I saw that one, but after converting it from fixed width/height to % had the same issue, will try again later, ty.

Comment: NP. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this differently using multiple background:

```css
.box {
  width:250px;
  border-radius:500px 500px 0 0;
  background:
     /* a linear gradient to control the progress. Adjust the angle from 0deg to 180deg*/
     linear-gradient(160deg,transparent 50%,#fff 0) top/100% 200%,
     /* a radial gradient to show only a part of the gradient (20px here)*/
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom,#fff calc(100% - 20px),transparent 0),
     /* the main gradient */
     linear-gradient(to right, green , yellow , red);
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

That you can optimize with CSS variables:

```css
.box {
  --p:160deg;
  --b:20px;
  
  width:250px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:500px 500px 0 0;
  background:
     /* a linear gradient to control the progress. Adjust the angle from 0deg to 180deg*/
     linear-gradient(var(--p),transparent 50%,#fff 0) top/100% 200%,
     /* a radial gradient to show only a part of the gradient (20px here)*/
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom,#fff calc(100% - var(--b) - 1px),transparent calc(100% - var(--b))),
     /* the main gradient */
     linear-gradient(to right, green , yellow , red);
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--b:30px;--p:90deg"></div>
<div class="box" style="--b:10px;--p:40deg"></div>
```

Another syntax:

```css
.box {
  --p:160deg;
  --b:20px;
  
  width:250px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:500px 500px 0 0;
  padding:var(--b) var(--b) 0;
  background:
     linear-gradient(var(--p),transparent 50%,#fff 0) top/100% 200%,
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff) content-box,
     linear-gradient(to right, green , yellow , red);
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--b:30px;--p:90deg"></div>
<div class="box" style="--b:10px;--p:40deg"></div>
```

And using mask to have transparency:

```css
.box {
  --p:160deg;
  --b:20px;
  
  width:250px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-radius:500px 500px 0 0;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, green , yellow , red);
  -webkit-mask:
     radial-gradient(farthest-side at bottom,transparent calc(100% - var(--b) - 1px),#fff calc(100% - var(--b))),
     linear-gradient(var(--p),#fff 50%,transparent 0) top/100% 200%;
  -webkit-mask-composite:destination-in;
          mask-composite:intersect;
}
.box::before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top:50%;
}

body {
  background:#f3f3f3;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--b:30px;--p:90deg"></div>
<div class="box" style="--b:10px;--p:40deg"></div>
```

Comment: Do you know how to make .box width a percentage like 50% of the parent? Since you used 500px border-radius for a 250px width .box, I tried using 100% radius for a 50% width .box, but didn't work correctly: https://jsfiddle.net/c39w2u5z/

Comment: @Mark use a very big value like 5000px or even 100vmax. It need to be a length and not a percentage https://jsfiddle.net/zowv4k1u/